# show errors using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to highlight a list of input received in an array and give the focus to the first of them.

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='app.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <script>showErrors(['firstName', 'lastName'])</script>
</body>
```

in app.js, I put the following javascript code:

```
function showErrors($fields)
{
    $fields.forEach(function($field){
        console.log($field);
        $('#'+$field).addClass('error-custom');
        $('#'+$field).css('border', 'red solid 2px');
    });

    //set focus to first field
    if($fields.length > 0)
    {
        $('#'+$fields[0]).focus();
    }
}
```

The JS code is executed but before the page is rendered.
I tried to put the function showErrors into `$(document).ready(function(){...}` but it still had no effect.

Where should I place the code so I can have apply after the page is rendered?

Comment: if the page is "built" dynamically by code that you haven't shown, do it after that ... otherwise `$(document).ready(function(){ ...your code here...})` should be the right place to do it

Comment: and you should consider adding a border in css if that border should only be visible when the element has the `error-custom` class.

Comment: You mention "app.js"... Are you using any kind of framework besides jQuery? I also don't see jQuery referenced in your HTML; a lot of people forget that step.

Comment: @JaromandaX: I have put all the function `showError($fields)` inside the block `$(document).ready(function(){showError($fields){...rest of code ..}});`
when I open the page in Chrome, it shows the following error in the development tool: "Uncaught ReferenceError: showErrors is not defined"

when I view the source Ctrl+U in chrome, the app.js is correct and when I click on its link, it shows my code.

Comment: @DawidZbiński: the class 'error-custom' highlits correctly and I tested in some other fields.
@MikeMcCaughan: I've linked my page to jQuery but forgot to show it in this question
like so `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/crm/public/js/jquery.min.js'></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my errors was that I called the javascript function showError before rendering the input fields which were after.

I simply moved the call at the end of the page.

Answer (score 1):

looks like it works with $(document).ready(function(){ } ... don't know why you are pre-pending $ to your fields variable though it does nothing this isn't php ;)

```js
function showErrors($fields)
{
 $fields.forEach(function($field){
  console.log($field);
  $('#'+$field).addClass('error-custom');
  $('#'+$field).css('border', 'red solid 2px');
 });
 
 //set focus to first field
 if($fields.length > 0)
 {
  $('#'+$fields[0]).focus();
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='app.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="firstName"/>
  <input type="text" id="lastName" />
  <script>$(document).ready(function(){showErrors(['firstName', 'lastName']);});</script>
</body>
```